# Tons of Logcat output in Nexus 5 ... BluetoothAdapter

Tags: android, nexus-5

In my Nexus5 logcat output I get tons of the following messages. What does it mean? Can I stop it? My Bluetooth is off.

```
08-21 20:42:16.760 D/BluetoothAdapter( 1042): 225483142: getState() :  mService = null. Returning STATE_OFF
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means that one of running applications or services asking for current Bluetooth state.
To stop it you have to figure out which exactly service or application needs that and stop it.